# How does the system find the best-matching Resource?

Tags: android

I have a `hdpi` device.
DPI: hdpi, density: 1.5, densityDpi: 240, sw: 320

`values` and `values-xxhdpi` folders.
Why Android takes `dimes` from `values-xxhdpi` not from `values`?

I assumed it should take it from a smaller folder.
And default values is mdpi and also hdpi is closser to mdpi then to xxhdpi.

Could you please tell me where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Densities are handled differently than other resource set constraints.

Android density resource set constraints are designed for use with `drawable` and `mipmap`. For those resources, Android can automatically convert the resource from one density to another, by upsampling or downsampling the image. This is not the case for other resource set constraints. For example, Android cannot automatically convert an English string resource to Chinese.

When it comes to finding a compatible resource, if you use densities as a constraint for the type (e.g., `values`), Android behaves as though it can convert the resource from one density to another... even for resource types where that is impossible. So, Android is choosing the closest density, using whatever algorithm it would use for choosing the image to convert, even though you are using the density qualifier on something other than images.

Using density as a qualifier for anything other than `drawable` or `mipmap` is a code smell. You are unlikely to get what you want.

Comment: Hello Mark, thank you for the answer.
So I should use `values-large` or `values-sw600dp` rather that `values-xxhdpi`, right?

Comment: @Yvgen: Yes. Changing values based on size is safe; changing values based on density is less safe.